Interactive data column selection for plotting using pure html/js (i.e. htmlwidgets) e.g. with checkBoxGroups/radioButtons/selectboxes
My dataset has multiple value columns (of the order of 100) and a time column. The data should be plotted in an independent html-document. Is there some possibility to interactively select the columns of the data to be plotted, e.g. by checkBoxGroups (at best) or multiple lists of radiobuttons/selectboxes, etc.?
It would be an easy task in shiny, but then the user has to run the app (or I have to host it) which both is not preferred. So I am looking for a pure html/js solution (probably htmlwidgets-based) that will work in a standard browser.
The plots should also feature more interactivity as given for example by plotly (being able to use ggplot would be great), dygraphs, etc. like zooming in/out, mouse hover, etc.
Currently I create multiple dygraphs which allow me to hover the values and to select areas of the plots synchronously among all plots (having the same group), but plotting all of them makes it hard to compare specific plots.
---
title: "sample_project"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---
```{r}
library(dygraphs)
# some sample data
set.seed(42)
mydata <- data.frame(Time = seq(as.POSIXct("2024-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2024-08-01"), by = "10 days"), 
                     Value1 = round(runif(22, 0, 10), 1), 
                     Value2 = round(runif(22, 0, 50), 1), 
                     Value3 = round(runif(22, 3, 5), 2))

dygraph(mydata[, c("Time", "Value1")], group = 'data') %>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>%
  dyUnzoom() %>%
  dyCrosshair(direction = "both")

dygraph(mydata[ , c("Time", "Value2")], group = 'data') %>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>%
  dyUnzoom() %>%
  dyCrosshair(direction = "both")

dygraph(mydata[ , c("Time", "Value3")], group = 'data') %>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>%
  dyUnzoom() %>%
  dyCrosshair(direction = "both")
# ```


In shiny I could do something like this (with a more sophisticated plot and interface of course):
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "select", label = "Select columns", choices = 2:4, selected = c(2), inline = T),
  plotOutput(outputId = "my_plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mydata[ , c(1, as.numeric(input$select))])
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)

